# Flask-SQLAlchemy move data from production db to staging db

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask, one of my application has gone live. Now I am puzzled on how I can copy data from production db back to staging db. All my models were declared using Flask-SQLAlchemy. Flask-SQLAlchemy supports multiple database connections. But my models are the same.

I wanted to reuse my database models and theoretically do the following:

```
db-production = ...
db-staging = ...

model1-p = db-production.model1

for item in model1-p:
   db-staging.add(item)

db-staging.commit()
```

How can I easily copy data cross? Any shortcuts?

Cheers.

Comment: You can export/dump the data from the production db and directly import it in the staging db. I'm not sure which database you're using so I can't give the exact steps. Also note that this method has nothing to do with Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am using Oracle database. I did a lookup on internet. There seems to be some utilities for these. Learning..